# Как изменить расположение камеры используя кнопку?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Пытаюсь настроить изменение расположения камеры с помощью кнопки но увы не меняет расположение.
Кнопки отрисовывает, ошибок не выдаёт, но и расположение камеры не меняет.

Вот код :

```
... 

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );
... 

... 

                  var controls2 = new function () {
                   this.pozishon = 0; 
                   if (this.pozishon==1) {
                    camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );
                   }
                   if(this.pozishon==2) {
                    camera.position.set( 0, 200, 400 );
                   }
                   if(this.pozishon==3 ) {
                   //   camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
                    //camera.position.set( 400, 400, 0 );
                   
                   camera.position.set( 400, -1800, 800);
camera.lookAt( 400, 400, 0 );
camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                   }
                   
                   };
                 
                gui = new GUI( { title: 'меню' } );
                const geometryFolder  = gui.addFolder("камера");
                geometryFolder.add(controls2, "pozishon", { 'прямо': 1, 'верх':2, 'бок': 3 }).name("камера");
                //geometryFolder.add(controls, 'rotationSpeed', 0, 0.5);
                //geometryFolder.add(controls, 'bouncingSpeed', 0, 0.5);
                const primitiveFolder =  gui.addFolder("примитивы");
                 
...
```

Comment: А с чего оно должно менять расположение камеры? Где, когда и (главное) почему положение должно поменяться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть что-то типа такого:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GUI } from "three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js";

console.clear();

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-3, 5, 8).setLength(12);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
//renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let controls2 = {
  pozishon: 0
}

let gui = new GUI({ title: "меню" });
const geometryFolder = gui.addFolder("камера");
geometryFolder
  .add(controls2, "pozishon", { "прямо": 1, "верх": 2, "бок": 3 })
  .name("камера")
  .onChange(val => {
  switch(val){
    case 1:
      camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);
      break;
    case 2:
      camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
      break;
    case 3:
      camera.position.set(5, 5, 10);
      break;
    default:
      alert("Что-то пошло не так")
  }
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
});
const primitiveFolder = gui.addFolder("примитивы");

renderer.setAnimationLoop((_) => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

У контроллера добавляется обработчик события `.onChange()`.

Comment: Спасибо что научили делать вот такую штуку (реально круто)

Comment: @timob256 Пожалуйста :) На самом деле это всего лишь пример одного из множества вариантов, и рассматривать как финальное решение его не нужно. Но если и в таком виде работает - тогда хорошо, рад, что смог помочь )

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GUI } from "three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js";
import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';

console.clear();

let camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        let stats, container;
        let gui;

        init();
        //render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
        animate();

        function init() {
            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x94afb5 );
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x94afb5, 0.002 );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            //document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            //container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
         
            //container=document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );

            // controls

            controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.listenToKeyEvents( window ); // optional

            //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

            controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

            controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

            controls.minDistance = 100;
            controls.maxDistance = 500;

            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

            // world
                 // рисую квадраты осей 

//--------------Создаем объект-------------------
const points = [];
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 10, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, -10, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, -10, 0));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 10, 0));
const osxyMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x7457bd, linewidth: 1 });
const osxyGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
const osxy = new THREE.Line(osxyGeometry, osxyMaterial);
scene.add(osxy);

const points1 = [];
points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 10));//Указываем вектор первой точки
points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 10));//Указываем вектор второй точки
points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, -10));
points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, -10));
points1.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 10));
const osxzMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x3d803d, linewidth: 1 });
const osxzGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points1);
const osxz = new THREE.Line(osxzGeometry, osxzMaterial);
scene.add(osxz);

const points2 = []
points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 10));//Указываем вектор первой точки
points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 10));//Указываем вектор второй точки
points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, -10));
points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, -10));
points2.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 10));
const osyzMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xab5641, linewidth: 1 })
const osyzGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points2)
const osyz = new THREE.Line(osyzGeometry, osyzMaterial)
scene.add(osyz) 

            // lights

            const dirLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            dirLight1.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( dirLight1 );

            const dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            dirLight2.position.set( - 1, - 1, - 1 );
            scene.add( dirLight2 );

            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

           // тут!!! статистика. 

            stats = new Stats();
            //container.appendChild( stats.dom );
             document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );
            //
            
            // tyt knopki
            
            let controls2 = {
  pozishon: 0
}

let gui = new GUI({ title: "меню" });
const geometryFolder = gui.addFolder("камера");
geometryFolder
  .add(controls2, "pozishon", { "прямо": 1, "верх": 2, "бок": 3 })
  .name("камера")
  .onChange(val => {
  switch(val){
case 1:
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);
  break;
case 2:
  camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
  break;
case 3:
  camera.position.set(5, 5, 10);
  break;
default:
  alert("Что-то пошло не так")
  }
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
});
const primitiveFolder = gui.addFolder("примитивы");

renderer.setAnimationLoop((_) => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            stats.update();
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

</script>
```